# Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration after if

Tags: if-statement, token

I don't know why after I added my last `if` statement, I got this error.
My code was working well, but after I added the `if` I got this error. I would really appreciate if you could help me fix this.

```
string answer = Console.ReadLine();
if (answer == "cold" || answer == "a cold")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Well done you may pass");
    Console.WriteLine("Doors are now Open");
    Console.ReadLine();
}



else if (selection == "W" ||selection == "w" && answer != "cold" || answer != "a cold") 
{
    characterHealth = characterHealth - 20;
    Console.WriteLine("Wrong Answer Try Again");
    Console.WriteLine("Your health level is: {0}", characterHealth);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
else if (selection == "S" || selection == "s" && answer != "cold" || answer != "a cold")
{
    characterHealth = characterHealth - 10;
    Console.WriteLine("Wrong Answer Try Again");
    Console.WriteLine("Your health level is: {0}", characterHealth);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

}
int dragonHealth = 150;
int strike = randomNumbers.Next(1, 30);
int strike1 = randomNumbers.Next(1, 50);
Console.Writeline("As you move on you are encountering a small dragon");
while (dragonHealth >= 0 && characterHealth >= 0)
{
    dragonHealth = dragonHealth - strike1;
    characterHealth = characterHealth - strike; 
    Console.WriteLine("You strike the dragon,  its health is: {0}", dragonHealth);
    Console.WriteLine("The dragon counters,  your health is: {0}", characterHealth);

    if ( characterHealth >= 0 && dragonHealth <= 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Congratulations you have killed the dragon");
        Console.WriteLine("You found the tresure, Story ends here");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    if ( characterHealth <= 0 && dragonHealth >=0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You died Game over");
        return;
    }
    if ( characterHealth <= 0 && dragonHealth <=0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You both died at the same time bad luck");
        return;
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Ugh, please format your code. Most editors can even do that automatically for you.

Comment: There's an extra close brace right before `int dragonHealth = 150;`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is only partial and so I can't be 100% certain, but I believe that the error is caused by mismatched or misplaced braces `{}`. You're practically asking for this kind of error when you don't indent your code. Format your code properly and double-check your braces.

Particular places that seem peculiar to me:

```
 else if (selection == "S" || selection == "s" && answer != "cold" || answer != "a cold")
        {
        characterHealth = characterHealth - 10;
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong Answer Try Again");
        Console.WriteLine("Your health level is: {0}", characterHealth);
        Console.ReadLine();
        }

 } //what does this brace close?
...
while (dragonHealth >= 0 && characterHealth >= 0)
    { //where is this brace closed?
```

As a side note unrelated to your actual question, learning some object-oriented programming or at very least the use of methods would help you make larger text adventure games with less effort!